# Apply force in newton to object

Tags: math, physics, game-physics, 2d-games

I have trouble finding out how much i have to change the velocity of a object if a force in newton is applied to that object:

[image]

**What i have:**
no gravity or other forces
deltaTime - Time in seconds since the last tick
v - the velocity of the object in units/second
m - the mass of the object in kg
d - the direction of the applied force

**What i want to do:**
for the time of one tick (deltaTime) i want to apply a force of `x Newton` in the direction `d` to the object. Actually i want to change the velocity of the object accordingly.

**What i did:**
I tried to come from `1 N = 1 kg * m/s2` to the change in velocity but i am a bit lost since i can`t figure out how to verify my assumptions.

**Update**
What i actually need is to now the acceleration caused by the force during `deltaTime` so i can calculate my new velocity by adding the acceleration like this:
`newVelocity = velocity + accelerationCausedByTheForceInNewton`

Comment: Does this help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_of_motion#Uniform_acceleration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_of_motion#Uniform_acceleration

Assuming a coordinate system (x and y directions), you can separate these... your direction d will have x and y components, as well as your velocity and acceleration. In your picture the acceleration is "straight down" (ax = 0), and your velocity is "only to the right" (vy = 0), but I doubt you can assume that at all times, so I won't.  These split everything into x and y components:

```
x1 = x0 + vx0(t1 - t0) + (1/2)(ax0)((t1 - t0)**2)
y1 = y0 + vy0(t1 - t0) + (1/2)(ay0)((t1 - t0)**2)
```

also, new velocities at t1:

```
vx1 = vx0 + ax0(t1 - t0)
vy1 = vy0 + ay0(t1 - t0)
```

So... your new x location is (1) the initial x location, added to (2) the x-component of velocity times delta-t, added to (3) half the x-component of acceleration times delta-t-squared. This can be simpler if, as in your picture `vx = 0` and/or `ay = 0`, but the above equations will work for the general case.

PS, based on `F=ma`, if you only know the force F going in, then:

```
 ax0 = Fx0 / m
 ay0 = Fy0 / m
```

Comment: `PS, based on F=ma, your acceleration is your force (in Newtons) divided by your mass (in kilograms), which will give an acceleration in meters per second-squared.` well said but i seek the acceleration (what i add to my current velocity) in the same form as my velocity (which is m/s). And if i would have the acceleration in m/s could't i just add a vector with the direction of `d` and length of my acceleration in m/s to my velocity to get my resulting velocity?

Comment: I've added the velocity adjustments to the answer; these also follow from the formulae given at the Wikipedia link.

Comment: What is unclear to me in both examples is how to calculate ax0 and ay0. What i came up with from `A Newton is the force it takes to make 1 kg change its velocity by 1 m/s every second.` is `newVelocity = velocity + (unitDirectionOfForce * (forceInNewton / massInKg)) * deltaTimeInSeconds`

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly: `a0 = (F0 / m)` ... replace accordingly throught the equations; making sure F is in Newtons and m is in kg; (modded the answer accordingly)

Comment: Just to be sure. If `d` is a unit vector and my mass is 5kg and the Force 10N my new velocity would be calculated like this: `deltaTime = t1 - t0; newVelocity = oldVelocity + d * (deltaTime * (10N / 5kg));`and to double check - if deltaTime would be exactly one second and the force would only go downwards the velocity would change by exactly `Vector(x: 0, y: 2)` ?